# Pass variable to npm scripts

Tags: javascript, npm-scripts

I need to develop multiple apps.

Each app has the same codebase. A ***json file*** defines which feature/class/controller have to be used for different app.

Now, I have a build task for each app.

I would like to be able to run a npm task and give to the task the json file.

I'm using webpack 4

Comment: No, this is not available in webpack.

Comment: Don't think it's about webpack but npm scripts

Comment: Yeah, indeed, better remove the webpack tag of this question though. You could create a cli that consumes the json and spawns the specific build for the key you gave it, and you run it with npm scripts.